# How do you do capture a hold drag gesture with the new input system of unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, input

As some people have noticed by now unity has introduced a new input system a while back now.

What i am trying to accomplish is a "hold right mouse button" + "move mouse" action. However i can't seem to find a way to add a "hold right mouse button" constraint option to accomplish this. Has someone made any experience with advanced action declarations which may be capable of solving this?

This is my current state:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.0/manual/KnownLimitations.html

At the bottom, it says it does not support OnMouseDrag which is what you are looking to do.

I tried to post an example code of c# OnMouseDrag but it gives me errors